# Passing parameter in meteor.js from template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to link to blog detail page from blog list, but the link does not work. What am I doing wrong here? this._id in the link is the correct id.
This is my route

```
this.route('blogdetail', {
    path: '/groupsmain/:_id/blogs/:paramOne',
    template:'groupdetail',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'blogdetail': {to: 'dynamiccontent'}
    },
    controller: blogdetailController
});
```

Blog list's url is

```
http://localhost:3000/groupsmain/NQxvBfeNQE875HDRR/blogs
```

and this is my link for blog detail

```
 <h3><a href="{{pathFor 'blogdetail' paramOne=this._id}}">{{this.title}}</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathFor` takes parameters from the current data context, not from the arguments you pass to it. So you need to alter the context with `#with` helper:

```
<a href="{{#with _id=_id paramOne=this._id}}{{pathFor 'blogDetail'}}{{/with}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current [Iron Router's code](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/909a865992887255dcbe62e3b69b6a53f3333296/lib/client/ui/helpers.js) (version 0.9.1), it looks like the `pathFor` helper uses the context only if you don't pass any arguments explicitly in the helper call. It may be a bug, since the docs examples show you could mix both cases.

So you either have to pass both parameters in the `pathFor` helper or have both values set in the context. You are passing only `paramOne` in the helper and expecting that Iron Router gets the `_id` parameter somewhere else. Try this:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'blogdetail' _id=whicheverIdYouNeedHere paramOne=_id}}">{{title}}</a>
```

If `whicheverIdYouNeedHere` is actually a property of the parent context, you can get it using the `..` keyword. You would end up with something like:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'blogdetail' _id=../nameOfThePropertyFromTheParentContext paramOne=_id}}">{{title}}</a>
```